# CSS transform, Jagged Edges in chrome

Tags: css, rotation, edges

i have a problem with jagged edges in chrome. Rest of browsers supporting this good but only chrome make this edges horible. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2HZ8A/
I tried with `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and it was working, but... i'm using parallax effects on my website and fixed top menu, when i put `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to .row1 and .row2 then everything's is crashing.

Comment: Can you be more specific and perhaps provide some screenshots? I'm seeing the exact same [view](http://i.imgur.com/3lZoh7R.png) rendered in Chrome Canary, Firefox, Safari, and Opera.

Comment: http://scr.hu/0abu/b677m
This is how it look in my chrome. Do you need screenshots of my website? Or maybe i upload it to ftp and send you an adress?

Comment: There is my website, http://lebsajt.pl/specify

Comment: it should be antialiased ;)
give me a cenond i will show you.

Comment: http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/zx/ds/oe/f3a07x.jpg

Comment: im using win8 and ie10 as well, know that but thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

I know this is about a year late, but this seems to work.

```
[class*="row"] {
   outline: 1px solid transparent;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JacobJWBurden/kkd5g5u7/